# What is a correct way of passing short data through user events in multi-threaded programs?

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, sdl

In my SDL2-based program I have the main thread that processes the event queue, and another thread that periodically pushes events to the it.

```
// thread #2
event.type = UserEventType;
event.user.code = SomeCode;
event.user.data = UInt8Value;
SDL_PushEvent(&event);
```

The main thread gets this event, and extracts data.

```
// main thread
SDL_PollEvent(&event); /* ... */
Uint8 Uint8Value = event.user.data;
```

This solution doesn't seem to be good, since the size of Uint8 and void* is different, and depends on platform. The safest way is to allocate Uint8-values in the heap and pass the pointer to it through event.user.data, and in main thread free the memory. But
isn't it non-efficient to alloc/free memory for each event, when all you need to pass is one byte? Maybe there is a better solution which is also portable?

Comment: It's a pain, isn't it - pushing small data items round producer-consumer queues? Is seems so inefficient and slow, (because it is).  Can the data not be buffered up to increase the size of data transferred and so reduce the inter-thread comms overhead?

Comment: In my case they can't. The data I'm sending stores information about user-generated input events (on a remote computer), so it should be processed (ideally) in real time.

Comment: Righht.. so you're stuck with this.  OK, what about a container of events forming a circular queue? You can load up the next free element and then push the address of it onto the queue.  The consumer/main can then deref it.  It's still going to be inefficient, but at least you avoid the pain of new/delete of tiny structs.

Comment: I approximately know how often _thread2_ generates events, and how often _main_ consumes them. So I know how big the circular queue should be. Your solution is good, thank you (-:

Comment: OK, I'll promote it to an actual answer, then:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a container of events forming a circular queue? You can load up the next free element and then push the address of it onto the queue. The consumer/main can then deref it. It's still going to be inefficient, but at least you avoid the pain of new/delete of tiny structs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it

```
//  All the possible character values
// Make this a global
char dummy_values[256];


// thread #2
event.type = UserEventType;
event.user.code = SomeCode;
event.user.data = dummy_values + UInt8Value;
SDL_PushEvent(&event);


// main thread
SDL_PollEvent(&event); /* ... */
Uint8 Uint8Value = static_cast<char*>(event.user.data) - dummy_values;
```

This is a cost of a 256 byte array, but it avoids dynamic memory and should be safe and portable

Comment: This code is hard to understand. I see no reason to manipulate with the address of dummy_values. I'd rather make it this way:

`// global?
Uint8 queue_ring[10];
int queue_index=0;

//thread2
queue_ring[queue_index]=UInt8Value;
event.user.data = &queue_ring[queue_index];
queue_index = (queue_index+1) % 10;
SDL_PushEvent(&event);

// main
Uint8 Uint8Value = *(Uint8*)event.user.data;`

Comment: the solution is interesting though

Comment: You code will fail if you have more than 10 variables pending. My code will not. The dummy_values is not actually used to save anything. In C, you cannot necessarily convert from an integer to a pointer. However, if you use an array, you can convert from a pointer to an offset, and from an offset to a pointer provided offset is less than the number of elements in the array. Here we know that our offset is max 255 (due to it being uint8). Therefore we can convert every value to a valid pointer by adding the offset to the starting address of dummy_values. We reverse the process to convert back.